# Future returns null when trying to read fields from a document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a future that returns a map that is

```
Future<Map<String, String>> getOtherUserInfo() async {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
          .get()
          .then((data) {
        var map = {
          "email": data.get("email"),
        };
        return map;
      });
    }
  }
```

And `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null` is `true` in this case.

For some reason, instead of returning `map`, which is not `null`, the future returns `null`. I've also checked the `.then((data) {do something})` does indeed run.

Edit: Also realized that if I do

```
.then((data) {
        return {"this_is_a_sample_map", "value"};
      });
```

it still returns `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your method. This should work:

```
Future<Map<String, String>> getOtherUserInfo() async {
  return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
    ? await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((data) => { "email": data.get("email"), }
    : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first reason of getting null is possible null current user. It could be handled by else statement with returning error.

The second, chaos of await / then style async usages. So if you want to go with `then` style, follow below

```
Future<Map<String, String>> getOtherUserInfo() {

  Completer<Map<String, String>> completer = Completer();

  if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((data) {
        var map = {
          "email": data.get("email"),
        };
        completer.complete(map);
    });

  } else {
    completer.completeError("No current firebase user!");
  }

  completer.future;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define the map at the beginning of the function and return it at the end not inside (then) like this

```
Future<Map<String, String>> getOtherUserInfo() async {
var map;
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
          .get()
          .then((data) {
        map = {
          "email": data.get("email"),
        };
       
      });
    }
 return map;
  }
```